# Elliptic PDE on the Whole Space

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-operators

Can anyone suggest a reference for elliptic PDE on the all of $\mathbb{R}^d$, as opposed to some bounded domain $\Omega$, covering the standard topics of existence, uniqueness, and regularity.  I specifically mean elliptic operators with variable coefficients, so these problems cannot be automatically treated by the Fourier transform.  The only reference I've found is Krylov's book.  Everything else (Gilbarg & Trudinger, Evans), seem to be limit themselves to bounded subsets with sufficiently regular boundary.

Comment: In variational methods, you can check WIillem's book "Minimax Theorems ", "Invitation to variational methods" by David Costa and "Semilinear Elliptic Equations for Beginners"by Badiale & Serra. In all this books there are chapters talking about problems in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$